# difference between accessing a property via "propertyname" versus "self.propertyname" in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, properties, accessor

What is the nce between accessing a property via "propertyname" versus "self.propertyname" in objective-c?  Can you cover in the answer:

1. What is best practice?
2. How do the two approaches affect memory management (retain counts / one's responsibilities for memory management)
3. Any other advantages/disadvantages

The assumption for the scenario could be based on the following:

*Header file*

```
@interface AppointmentListController : UITableViewController {
    UIFont *uiFont;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIFont *uiFont;
```

*Implementation*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  

    uiFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    //VERSUS
    self.uiFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `propertyname` just accesses the *instance variable*. You're responsible for doing your own memory management on its contents; no retains or releases are performed for you.

Using `self.propertyname` generally uses an *accessor*. If you're using `@synthesize`, the generated accessors will handle memory management as specified in your `@property` line (the example you gave uses `retain`, so a retain will be performed on setting a new value to `self.propertyname`). You can also write your own accessor methods that do management as you like.

A fuller explanation is in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003539-SW1). Best practices in this case are generally to use `@property` and `@synthesize` to handle your variables, then use the `self.propertyname` accessors to reduce the memory management burden on yourself. The guide also recommends you avoid implementing custom accessors (i.e. using `@property` without `@synthesize`).

Comment: I for one normally name my instance variables `_propertyname` so the compiler will complain if I accidentally leave off the `self.`.

Comment: That's a practice I've adopted too - it helps to set apart instance from property more clearly.

Comment: oh, so if I'm currently just using propertyname I would need to specifically put in a retain else risk losing the variable then?  What about best practice however, is it to use the accessor? (which interestingly is more verbose)

Comment: @Anomie/@Tim - what do you mean here exactly?  So within the interface section of the header file call the variable "UIFont *_uiFont"?  But then in the @property line how to you get a "uiFont" property to line up with the "_uiFont" variable?

Comment: @Greg: You match them up in the synthesize directive: `@synthesize uiFont = _uiFont;`

Answer (score 1):

An additional note - It's not so useful for the iPhone, since there aren't bindings in Cocoa Touch. But if you're using Cocoa, it's useful to note the following:

Key-Value Coding. KVC is a protocol used throughout Cocoa, most notably in bindings. It will look for accessors for your keys first, and only access data directly as a last resort. You can shorten KVC's search and thus speedup data access by implementing accessors.

Also be aware that if you set instance variables directly, in the form of var = value, Key-Value Observing will not notice the change and bound objects will not get the new value.

Comment: This is actually relevant in iOS development as well, since objects there do support KVC and KVO, albeit in a bit of an abridged form. Thanks for pointing it out!