# When to use [self.obj message] vs [obj message]

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to access properties with 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271657/when-to-access-properties-with-self)
>   [In Objective-C on iOS, what is the (style) difference between “self.foo” and “foo” when using synthesized getters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494157/in-objective-c-on-ios-what-is-the-style-difference-between-self-foo-and-foo)

For example sake, I have a `@property` named `obj` and I `@synthesize` it. So when do I need to use `[self.obj message]` vs `[obj message]` in my implementation class.

Comment: There's a search box in the upper right corner of the page.  Use it.  This question has been asked a dozen times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two great tutorials that cover this issue well:

[Understanding your (Objective-C) self](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/8/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html)

[When to use properties & dot notation](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=160)

Comment: Those examples really helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `self`, the getter method will be called. Thus, any additional logic in this getter method is executed. This is especially useful when instance variables are lazy loaded through their getters.

I myself try to use `self` most of the time. Lazy loading is just an example, another thing is that with `self`, subclasses may override the getter to get different results.

Using `self` to set a variable is even more useful. It will trigger KVO notifications and handle memory management automatically (when properly implemented, of course)

Comment: Excellent mention of lazy loading. The logic is centralized in the getter.

Answer (score 1):

When synthesize a property, the compiler declare a related ivar for you, in default, the ivar is the same as property name. I recommend use self.obj always to keep code cleaner, and avoid some potential bugs.

And I suggest you follow the good practice from Apple, `@synthesize obj=_obj`, the ivar will become `_obj`, when you mean to use property, this style force you to write `self.obj`, directly call `obj` will be error since the ivar is `_obj`.

Edit: automatically creating ivar for property is only in modern Objective-C runtime, it's safe in iOS SDK 4.0 and Mac OS X 10.6 above.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

> For @synthesize to work in the legacy
>   runtime, you must either provide an
>   instance variable with the same name
>   and compatible type of the property or
>   specify another existing instance
>   variable in the @synthesize statement.
>   With the modern runtime, if you do not
>   provide an instance variable, the
>   compiler adds one for you.

Comment: Properties are used to quickly declare efficient getters (and setters), no instance variable will be created.

Comment: @Joost That's true in the old Objective-C runtime, but in modern runtime, the property is really create an ivar for you.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, I revoked my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please search the site.  You'll often find that the exact question you're asking has been asked before:

- [difference between accessing a property via "propertyname" versus "self.propertyname" in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251600/difference-between-accessing-a-property-via-propertyname-versus-self-propertyn)
- [When to access properties with 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271657/when-to-access-properties-with-self)
- [self.variable and variable difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536388/iphone-different-between-self-and-normal-variable)
- [Objective-C: When to call self.myObject vs just calling myObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332389/when-to-call-self-myobject-vs-just-calling-myobject-in-objective-c)
- [iVar property, access via self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088801/ivar-property-access-via-self)
- [Should I Use self Keyword (Properties) In The Implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051543/should-i-use-self-keyword-properties-in-the-implementation)
- [In Objective-C on iOS, what is the (style) difference between "self.foo" and "foo" when using synthesized getters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494157/in-objective-c-on-ios-what-is-the-style-difference-between-self-foo-and-foo)
- [When to use self on class properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867001/when-to-use-self-on-class-properties)

... etc.

Comment: i will definitely do that next time.